# Finding distance between interpolated (to be) points and known points using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

To interpolate value of unknown points, first, i have to calculate the distance between unknown points and known points. I have array of x,y values with the size of (85, 1) and grid of unknown points from Xmin-Xmax,Ymin-Ymax with the increment of 500

```
#known points
x = f[:,[0]]
y = f[:,[1]]

#interpolated coordinates(unknown point)
xi = np.arange(minX,maxX,500)
xi=xi[np.newaxis, :].T
yi = np.arange(minY,maxY,500)
yi=yi[np.newaxis, :].T
```

I want to find distance between them and store them in an array. This is my attempt:

```
preDistX = []
preDistY = []

for u in xi:
    preDistX.append(x-u)
for u in yi:
    preDistY.append(y-u)
preDistX=np.array(preDistX)
preDistY=np.array(preDistY)
```

But as preDistX and preDistY have difference shape, i cannot directly calculate distance between them. I've tried using meshgrid for unknown points but it confuses me more. What should i do? I dont want to use iteration because I'm working with large number of arrays and that's not efficient at all.

Thank you!

Comment: can you insert example values for `f` and so for `x` and `y`?

Comment: x= array([[ 12100.],
       [  5300.],
       [  3500.],
       [  5100.],
       [  9900.],
       [  2900.],
       [  7900.],
       [ 16900.],
       [ 18700.],
       [  2700.],
       [ 10700.],
       [  7500.],

y = array([[  8300.],
       [  8700.],
       [ 13900.],
       [  1900.],
       [ 13700.],
       [   900.],
       [  6700.],
       [  4900.],
       [  1500.],
       [  2100.],